# Scrapy problems with requests

Tags: python, recursion, request, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape all the possible combinations of outputs of 5 dropdowns (working as tree depth) and make a generic tree data structure out of it.

I have the requests inside a for option in dropdown options and the spider only iterates each for loop once.

```
def parse(self, response):
    lastPos = response.meta['lastPos']
    ending = False
    for dropDown in reversed(response.css('select')):
        if ending == True:
            break
        dropId = dropDown.css('::attr(id)').get()
        options = dropDown.css('option::text').getall()
        for option in options:
            if option != self.root:
                self.dropDict[dropId] = option
                    request = scrapy.FormRequest(url=response.url, formdata=self.dropDict, callback=self.parse)
                    request.meta['lastPos'] = option
                    return request
```

the spider needs to iterate through 16 possible sequences, but I'm only able to get the first sequence which is always picking the first dropdown option. I can't send the repo of the spider is its helpful

Answer (score 2):

Use `yield request` instead of `retutn request`.

Comment: i was firstly using yield but what happens is that he iterates the whole for loop, but will only run the request once, at the last iteration, the output is the same but a different sequence

Comment: It looks like your application trying to parse the same url more than one time. Scrapy has built in duplicate filtering which is turned on by default. Try to add `dont_filter=True` as argument to `FormRequest`

Comment: yes, i have to do it since its the same page that i gotta run every time, need the url to check it out?